# Mapbox canvas rendering on half of the screen

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to use MapBox with React.js. This is my code:

```
import ReactMapboxGl, {Layer, Feature} from "react-mapbox-gl";

render() {
    const Map = ReactMapboxGl({
        accessToken: "..."
    });
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Map style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
                 containerStyle={{
                     height: "100vh",
                     width: "100vw",
                 }}>
                <Layer
                    style={{
                        position: 'absolute',
                        left: 0,
                        top: 0,
                    }}
                    type="symbol"
                    id="marker"
                    layout={{"icon-image": "marker-15"}}>
                    <Feature coordinates={[-0.481747846041145, 51.3233379650232]}/>
                </Layer>
            </Map>
            {/*<button onClick={this.requestLocation}>Refresh position</button>*/}
        </div>
    );
}
```

The problem is, this is the result:

[image]

It's always precisely 50% of the width. I'm using this module: https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl

What did I mess up?

Comment: This seems like a pretty common issue with that React wrapper: https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl/issues/669

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer, this is caused by come css conflcts.
Try to comment the text-align center for .App

```
.App {
   /* text-align: center; */
}
```

This should work!